# Target parent container and ignoring click events on child input checkbox in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, checkbox

I have the following piece of jQuery in my jQuery Mobile application where I am selecting the child checkbox when the `li` is clicked. This works fine, however it breaks the default functionality of the checkbox itself in the way that it makes it impossible to deselect the checkbox when clicking the box *directly*.

How can I target the `li` but *not* the checkboxes with the code?

```
var page = $.mobile.activePage
page.on('vclick', '.item_boxes_wrapper li:not(.item_checkbox)', function(e) {
   var checkbox = $(this).find(':input');
   checkbox.prop('checked', checkbox.is(':checked') ? null: 'checked');
});
```

```html
<ul class="item_boxes_wrapper">
   <li class="item_container selected_item">
      <img src="http://www.wrestlemaniamainevent.com/Image/984043-64-1.jpg" class="product_image">
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="98404364099" class="item_checkbox" name="items[]">
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Scumbag Steve. Downvotes post, but doesn't comment why. SMH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
page.on('vclick', '.item_boxes_wrapper li:not(.item_checkbox)', function(e) {
   if($(e.target).is(':checkbox')) return; // add this check here
   var checkbox = $(this).find(':checkbox'); // or .find('input[type=checkbox]')       
   checkbox.prop('checked', !checkbox.is(':checked'));
});
```

PS: doesn't seem relevant selector `.item_boxes_wrapper li:not(.item_checkbox)`, i guess you want `'.item_boxes_wrapper li'`. Or maybe `.item_boxes_wrapper li:not(:has(.item_checkbox))`???